# How to access remote iPhoto Library with FileVault on?

Tags: macos, mac, iphoto, filevault

After turning on FileVault on my MBA with Mavericks I can no longer access the iPhoto Library that I have on an external drive. It asks my to upgrade the iPhoto Library.

But, accessing it from my MBP with Mavericks and FileVault off I have no problem (and it doesn't ask me to upgrade the library).

Both computers are running the same versions of OS and iPhoto, the only difference being FileVault on/off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the latest OS update on the MBA fixed this issue.